# create java spring websocket server

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I am trying to create a WebSocket server using Spring. I have done following:in my websocekt server end point code and main class code

--

```
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Configuration
    @ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/websocket", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
            MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE })
    public class WebSocketTest {

        @OnMessage
        public void onMessage(String message, Session session) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // Print the client message for testing purposes
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);

            // Send the first message to the client
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("This is the first server message");

            // Send 3 messages to the client every 5 seconds
            int sentMessages = 0;
            while(sentMessages < 3){
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                session.getBasicRemote().
                    sendText("This is an intermediate server message. Count: " 
                        + sentMessages);
                sentMessages++;
            }

            // Send a final message to the client
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("This is the last server message");
        }

        @OnOpen
        public void onOpen () {
            System.out.println("Client connected");
        }

        @OnClose
        public void onClose () {
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
        }
    }


@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(methods = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.DELETE,
        RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.HEAD })
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/api", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
        MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE })
// @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath*:classpath:applications.properties" })
public class TestController {

//REST functions

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Initiating Spring Boot Application");
        // readfile ();
//      WebSocketTest wsc = new WebSocketTest();
        SpringApplication.run(TestController.class, args);
    }
}
```

But the web socket is not created successfully.
i checked my client/UI code. It is correct. If I use an open websocket published

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
```

works
but

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/test/api/websocket');
```

does not works.

Comment: I think you are mixing j2ee Websocket specs with Spring websocket. Have you tried accessing  new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/test/websocket'); or  new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/websocket');  ?

Comment: I tried 

    new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/test/websocket'); 
    and new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/websocket');
    and new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/test/api/websocket');

It doesn't work.
Can see following error
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Comment: By the way are you sure about the port number ?